# How to mark up the information of a section of a reprint of a very old book in bibtex for use with the monthly style from the MAA?

Tags: bibtex

So I have a book first published in 1593, republished in the author's opera omnia in the 1646s, then that volume was reprinted (facsimile of the 1646 edition) in 1970, and this is the edition I am referencing.  I am using only the "Variorum" from the book.  The citation will be built by the "monthly" style provided by the MAA for use in the American Mathematical Monthly.  Ideally I just want the information to be in the right place with their style, it doesn't have to look exactly as below.  Here is the citation I am working with:

> Vieta, F., *Variorum de Rebus Mathematicis Reponsorum Liber VII*, (1593) in: *Opera Mathematica*, (reprinted) Georg Olms Verlag, Hildesheim, New York, 1970, pp. 398-400 and 436-446.

I guess that year should be 1970, but how to I mark up the original dates?  I don't see an original edition year, or "year that original book was published before appearing in the collected work of the author" field.  I'm guessing I should be leveraging the notes field?  Does anyone have any similar experience?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I think the "correct" answer depends largely on which version you actually consulted and wish to form the primary basis for the citation and reference. If you consulted the reprint edition (which, by the way, is missing some editor-related information), by all means cite that edition; for completeness, you could add information about the original edition in a `note` field. Conversely, if you found (and managed to decipher!) a hide-bound copy of the original, that's what you should cite.

Comment: It really depends on the bibliography/citation style. The Georg Olms Verlag reprints are (in my experience) facsimile reprints (without a modern editor). Is it a reprint of [this](http://books.google.ca/books?id=JmBDAAAAcAAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s)? Will you only be citing "varia"? Are you planning to use an author-date style?  which one? And are you using a traditional BibTeX package like `natbib` or the `biblatex` package?

Comment: Yes, the reprint is just a facsimile of the 1646 edition. It will be in the "monthly" style supplied by the MAA, so however that formats it, I guess?  And yes, I am only citing the "Varia" from it.

Comment: Make your best guess and ask the Monthly editor to comment on your choice and suggest improvements if s/he wants to.